# Is it possible to find some line in GoLand IDE VCS History?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, goland

There is action `Show history (VCS|Git)` in GoLand IDE that shows every version of file/files. I cant find way to search some text through all commits.

Is it possible to do something like `git grep <regexp> $(git rev-list --all)` in `History` window?

Comment: You can just type inside the window.

Comment: @artspb Hmmm... Just typing activates search by commit info (commit message, commiter, date etc.) not by commit content.
But how to find all `fmt.Println` for example from previous 100+ commits?

Comment: Ah, I see. Then it looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-109570 Is it what you need?

Answer (score -1):

Right-click on the line, then use `Git | Show History for Selection`.
Or use `Find action` (Ctrl+Shift+A on Windows/Linux, Cmd+Shift+A on macOS), and search for `shhisel`.

Comment: Mmm... It will open History Window. But main problem is find some specific text in history.